# WP_query wp_posts_counts returns only count of admin and not users

Tags: wp-query

the below query returns only count of an admin and not the posts submitted by any other user type (author/contributor) , can u please help in debugging

```
<?php
$jobs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'jobs' ,'author'=>$post_author ,
    'meta_key' => 'custom_status', 'meta_value' => 'active'));
if ($jobs->have_posts()) {

    $count_posts = wp_count_posts('jobs')->publish;

    echo "<h2>There is currently $count_posts posts...</h2>";
?>
```

Comment: i got it solved , i used the get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ); to get the author name instead of get_the author()

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please post your solution as an answer, then stop by in  a couple of days and click the check mark to accept it. This will close the question out of the unanswered queue.